# Will social sharing result in banning my Google AdSense account?

Tags: google-adsense, social-media

I have an approved Google AdSense account for a new website. To promote my website, I share the blogs on social media. ***If people click on the Ads through the link which I shared on social media, can it result in banning my Google Adsense account?***

I am sharing a direct link on social media so, Google's algorithm may consider the ad clicks as clicks by family/friends (basically unfair) and may ban my AdSense account.

In reality, I am sharing it on social media (but not with my friends) just to promote and don't know at all who clicks the ad.